# Get broken data as a row in Python

Tags: python

I have a txt file from where I am reading data line by line using file handling, something like this.

```
file = open(input_file,'r') #input file is the path of the file
filelines = file.readlines()
file.close()
counter = 0

complete_line = ""
line_start = 
for line in filelines:
    print("Line number counter {} and data is -- {}".format(counter,line))
    if counter > 50:
       break
    counter += 1
```

Everything is working fine but there is one abnormality in data. When I print the line, they look like this:

```
FAR:A|4|2
MIR:||FT4232HAQ_QFN64|J750_036-1|J750|10:43:10 13-Oct-2020|10:47:01 13-Oct-2020|
 prod||0|||||IG-XL|3.50.40 (P1402)
SDR:1|0|0,1,2,3|||||||0|0
PMR:1|3|0||VCC3IO|1|0
PMR:1|3|4||VCC3IO|1|1
PMR:1|3|12||VCC3IO|1|2
```

The abnormality is, Python is reading `prod||0|||||IG-XL|3.50.40 (P1402)` as a separate line but it is not correct. It has to go with the previous line `MIR:||FT4232HAQ_QFN64|J750_036-1|J750|10:43:10 13-Oct-2020|10:47:01 13-Oct-2020|`. This is the case with many other lines. Basically, it should be considered one line unless the line starts with PMR,SDR,MIR.. and some other prefix.

As a workaround, I have replaced all the "[space]\n" with "" with the help of sublime text editor. But that doesn't work. It is still reading `prod||0|||||IG-XL|3.50.40 (P1402)` as a separate line.

Is there any elegant way to do it with Python or programming in general?

Comment: Is it just line wrap? (line too long to print, so it gets split into two lines)

Comment: I believe no. print("Line number counter {} and data is -- {}".format(counter,line)) gives the prod part in a separate line number so I don't think that's the case.

Comment: And you are sure there is no `\n` in that line?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, as I have removed it through sublime text regex replace.

Comment: Does `print(repr(line))` show a `\n`?

Comment: "Basically, it should be considered one line unless the line starts with PMR,SDR,MIR.. and some other prefix." Okay, and what is the rule that tells you whether something is one of those prefixes? Is there an explicit list of them? Or do you want to look, for example, for three capital letters followed by a colon? Or something else?

Comment: Could you check whether the first and second rows in the text file have the same line endings?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As of now there is no list, but these prefixes are finite set of values(maybe 10-20), so I can construct them if needed.

Comment: @GZ0 If I got you right, no the ending need not to be same.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch Thanks, it seems like there got one \n in there while saving. So as of now, I have rectified it and they are in the same line. But is there any way to get this done using python ? Client don't expect to open sublime and make any changes from there.

Comment: [Line endings](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html). In some circumstances, you can end up with a file that mixes up the endings, which can cause problems. Most text editors should detect this and warn you about it. If you want to be really sure, you can check with a hex editor, or by reading the file in binary mode.

Comment: " it seems like there got one \n in there while saving." Well, the way to fix this problem depends on exactly what the problem is. If "while saving" means that you created the data with sublime text... will you need to create it that way again, or edit it that way? But if the data comes from another Python program (or from somewhere else in this one), then there is a problem with the code logic.

Comment: Thank @KarlKnechtel I will surely check out the mentioned link. However, can you suggest some pythonic way to get this done? As I said in the above comment, the client wants everything to be automatic and very little manual intervention.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel NO, actually while saving the file, I mistakenly clicked entered and saved.

Comment: Oh, well in that case I am voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think I failed to make you understand. There is issue with the actual file, so when I read line by line, some of the data shifts to other line. This I temporarily fixed using the sublime text editor. But, I need some pythonic solution to it.

Comment: Well, the file should be fixed. Reading the file only gives you what is actually there. Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too large to fit into the memory, you can use regular expressions:

```
import re

with open(input_file,'r') as f:
    lines = re.sub(r"\n\s+", "", f.read()).split('\n')
```